# How can I remove old variables of renamed flexform variables in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

I added a FlexForm to my Extension, where i have 14 variables like:

```
<settings.flex.usernameMinimumLengthActive>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>LLL:EXT:rm_registration/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:extension_flexform.usernameMinimumLengthActive</label>
        <config>
            <type>check</type>
            <items type="array">
                <numIndex index="1" type="array">
                    <numIndex index="0">LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled</numIndex>
                    <numIndex index="1">1</numIndex>
                </numIndex>
            </items>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.flex.usernameMinimumLengthActive>
```

inside the `<el> </el>` part.

I changed the names of all variables (`settings.flex.xxx`).

My debug shows up all variables: the new and the old.

My Question: how can I remove the old variables?

### I tried

- Clear Cache in BE (System, Frontend)
- Clear Cache (Installtool)
- Clear FE-Browser-Cache
- Another Browser

I still have all variables incl. the old names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I got a solution

1. ID of the Plugin

In the List- or the Page-Module I hover the PluginIcon. There I got the Uid of that Plugin I want to configure.

2. In Adminer (t3adminer installed from TER)

I clicked the Icon of `tt_content` (The FlexForm writes its config to a `tt_content` field called: `pi_flexform`).

I search for Uid of the Plugin and Edit the record.

3. Empty the field `pi_flexform`
   OR delete the old entries and Go to 8. (thanks to [Georg Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2389552/georg-ringer))
4. Go back to List- or Page-Module
5. Edit the Plugin
6. Reconfigurate the Plugin with Flexform
7. Save the Plugin (Now the FlexForm Settings fill the `pi_flexform` again only with the new settings)
8. Finish

Comment: you could also just remove the old settings there.

Comment: Thanks for this Annotation I will add this to my Answer.